# Retrofit 2 caching - chain of interceptors

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2

I need to implement basic caching of API responses. I've made a little playground project that calls GitHub API and caching was successful (I've used Charles to verify that). However when I transferred this solution to my target project caching didn't work anymore. Could multiple interceptors in the chain be the reason?

**Code from playground project (working):**

Interceptor (same for target project):

```
public class CacheControlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return response.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Cache and client declaration:

```
long SIZE_OF_CACHE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
final Cache cache = new Cache(new File(getCacheDir(), "retrofit_cache"), SIZE_OF_CACHE);

OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache);
client.networkInterceptors().add(new CacheControlInterceptor());

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/users/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client.build())
        .build();
```

Screen from debugging of CacheControlInterceptor:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQhiM.png)

**Code from target project (NOT working):**

Cache and client declaration:

```
private OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okhttpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okhttpClientBuilder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okhttpClientBuilder.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    okhttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    okhttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new JwtRenewInterceptor(getUserSession()));
    okhttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new AutoLoginInterceptor(getUserSession()));
    okhttpClientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(new CacheControlInterceptor());

    long SIZE_OF_CACHE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
    final Cache cache = new Cache(new File(getCacheDir(), "retrofit_cache"), SIZE_OF_CACHE);
    okhttpClientBuilder.cache(cache);

    return okhttpClientBuilder.build();
}
```

Screen from debugging of CacheControlInterceptor: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xi7z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the mistake was caused by my poor reasoning about http headers. I thought that method `addHeader` or `header` will simply add key `Cache-Control` and then value `only-if-cached`. However it adds only value! And since in my target project's API there was no header key `Cache-Control` (unlike in GitHub API) there was no place for value `only-if-cached` to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

If you want apply some headers to all requests using OkHttp cache you should use Application interceptor, not network interceptor. Otherwise, you are not giving cache mechanism a chance to return cached responses.
It's nicely illustrated on OkHttp wiki 
[image]

So most probably what is happening in your code is that you let `Cache` to store responses but you never use them since requests going to Cache are missing `only-if-cached` header.

Try
`okhttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new CacheControlInterceptor());`